# DD copy prematurely reports "no space left on device". Beyond hardware failure, what could have caused that?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, dd

I have an embedded device booting from SD card with 8GB internal flash (enumerating at `/dev/mmcblk1`). I used to be able to manipulate the flash just fine (as in, I know that it is actually 8GB and accessible at `/dev/mmcbkl1`). However recently I noticed that I was unable to `dd` a disk image I'd expect to work onto it. Upon further investigation it seems like the internal flash block device appears as smaller than what it actually is.

This is verified both by `blocksize`:

```
$ sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/mmcblk1
32096256
```

and by just filling it with zeros:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk1
dd: writing to `/dev/mmcblk1': No space left on device
62689+0 records in
62688+0 records out
32096256 bytes (32 MB) copied, 28.2086 s, 1.1 MB/s
```

32MB? I expected around 7.6GB!

I'm concerned that this means HW failure. Are there any other options?

Comment: Two possibilities: bad device (flash memory has finite use life) and device needs to be repartitioned: 1. Remove all partitions, making it all free space. 2. Create partitions of desired size. 3. Format them with desired file system(s).

Comment: Surely, the partitions are not a factor as I'm writing to the whole block device and not just a single partition from it? (Also no `/dev/mmcblk1pN` partition devices show up)